# Restore bootable USB flash drive to normal

Tags: macos, mac, usb-flash-drive, formatting, bootable-media

I’m trying to create a persistent installation of Parrot OS on my 16GB USB flash drive. I made the mistake of making the USB flash drive bootable without partitioning the drive into 2 in the beginning. Now I am unable to revert the USB flash drive back to normal.

I am using macOS. When I open Disk Utility the USB flash drive is only recognized as 701KB and I am unable to erase it using the `diskutil` in the command line since it gives the error:

> The chosen size is not valid for the chosen file system.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

I found [a similar post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38892407/117259) where someone had the same problem and just ran this `diskutil` command from the command line:

```
diskutil zeroDisk /dev/disk2
```

Such a simple fix, so hard to find.

Comment: In general, formatting a disk would get you what you wanted.  The built-in Mac Disk Utility GUI is sometimes useful for it, but the usefulness of the Disk Utility has lessened in the last five years.  (i.e. not showing all plugged in devices)

Comment: be aware that you might get and error (like in my case), such as "Error with zero disk erase: Couldn't open disk (-69879)"

Comment: @jjrr what did you do then ?

Comment: (sorry, I don't remember anymore exactly :/ -- maybe this https://stackoverflow.com/a/53052852/5533078 )

Answer (score 1):

Disk utility gives error because it detects the wrong identifier - what I did

was using `diskutil list` and then based on the memory size, could find the right Identifier - here disk2 - then I used `diskutil zeroDisk /dev/disk2`

[image]